# how to extract objects in R environment to plot them with grid.arrange?

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2

I have created multiple ggplot (`geom_bar`) with a loop in R.
I have named them with `assign(paste("gg_",i,sep=""), data)` so they are all named with `gg_***`
I want to make a list of all these objects to plot them together with `grid.arrange` like :

```
list_gg <- ls(pattern = "gg_Clumpp*")
grid.arrange(list_gg, nrow=length(list_gg))
```

If I check the list_gg file :

```
> list_gg
[1] "gg_ClumppK2"    "gg_ClumppK3maj" "gg_ClumppK3min" "gg_ClumppK4"    "gg_ClumppK5maj" "gg_ClumppK5min" "gg_ClumppK6"
```

But if I use `grid.arrange` I received this message :

```
> grid.arrange(list_gg)
Error in gList(list("gg_ClumppK2", "gg_ClumppK3maj", "gg_ClumppK3min",  : 
  only 'grobs' allowed in "gList"
In addition: Warning message:
In grob$wrapvp <- vp : Coercing LHS to a list
```

Of course, if I run one object of this list I obtain my plot.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Have you tried `patchwork`? You could probably pass your `list_gg` and get the results you want.

Comment: Or you could convert the ggplot objects in `list_gg` to grobs using the `ggplotGrob()` function before passing to `grid.arrange()`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I think my real problem is the extraction of the R objects. Because `list_gg` is a class character... It is not a real vector of object

Answer (score 0):

There's two parts to this question.  I'll offer an answer for both.

TL;DR - to arrange a list of plots, choose `patchwork` or `cowplot` or something else that can accommodate a list of ggplot objects.  To create the list of plots from names of objects (stored as a vector string), use `lapply()` and `get()`.

#### Why the error message?

The error message "`Error in gList(list("gg_ClumppK2", "gg_ClumppK3maj", "gg_ClumppK3min",  :  only 'grobs' allowed in "gList"`" you get when sending a list to `grid.arrange()` is quite simply that the function `grid.arrange()` cannot handle a list of plot objects.  The function will accept either accept a list of **grobs** or a sequence of gg objects as arguments.  So, if you had plot names `p1`, `p2`, `p3`, and `p4`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(disp, qsec)) + geom_line()
p2 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp)) + geom_point()
p3 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(cyl, carb)) + geom_point()
p4 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(as.factor(carb), mpg)) + geom_boxplot()
```

This would be valid to show all:

```
grid.arrange(p1, p2, p3, p4)
```

But this gives the error:

```
grid.arrange(list(p1, p2, p3, p4))
```

If you want to use a `list()` object containing plots - which is very useful here in your case - then I would suggest using any of the other packages that can do this.  `patchwork` should work, but I like using `cowplot` and the `plot_grid()` function.  Just be sure to assign the list explicitly to `plotlist=`, since the default argument design is similar to `grid.arrange()`.

```
cowplot::plot_grid(plotlist = list(p1, p2, p3, p4))
```

[image]

#### How to get a character vector of object names into a list?

As OP correctly mentions, the bigger issue here is that `list_gg` in their case is not a class list, but a vector of character names for those objects.  Using the example I show here, this is the difference between `c("p1", "p2", "p3", "p4")` and `list(p1, p2, p3, p4)`.

To convert a list of characters that are object names to a list, you need to first use the name (as a character) to reference the actual object.  You can use the `get()` function for this, since when you send `get("p1")`, you will return back the object itself.  You can combine this with `lapply()` over the character vector to add the objects into a list.

So in the current example I'm showing here:

```
list_gg <- c("p1", "p2", "p3", "p4")   # not a list

actual_list <- lapply(list_gg, function(x) {get(x)})  # returns a list
```

Then using the following works:

```
cowplot::plot_grid(plotlist = actual_list)
```

Comment: instead of the lapply(..., get(...)) thingy, you can also just use mget.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and for taking the time to detail all the steps.
It’s work perfectly now with only two lines :   

`actual_list <- lapply(ls(pattern = "gg_*"), function(x) {get(x)})
cowplot::plot_grid(plotlist = actual_list, nrow = length(actual_list))`